# Adding modal to upload image in a custom component in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, forms, modal-dialog, joomla2.5, image-uploading

I am trying to built my custom component, in which I want to upload image from administrator.
For uploading image I want to use media manager modal, and that should return the image url in my text box. I have made following changes in the popup-imagemanager.js:

```
this.editor = decodeURIComponent(q.get('e_name')); //after this
//I added
this.return_url = decodeURIComponent(q.get('return_url'));
```

and

```
//window.parent.jInsertEditorText(tag, this.editor);

//removed above line and added the following

if ( this.return_url == 1 ) 
{ 
 window.parent.document.getElementById(this.editor).value=url; 
} 
else 
{ 
 window.parent.jInsertEditorText(tag, this.editor); 
}
```

and the code in my form is as under:

```
<input class="text_area" type="text" name="imageurl" id="imageurl" size="50" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $this->image->image;?>" /> 

 <div class="button2-left"> 
  <div class="image"> 
   <a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 570, y: 400}}" href="index.php?      option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&e_name=imageurl&return_url=1"
   title="Image" class="modal-button">Select</a> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

When I click the insert button after selecting an image in the modal, I get the error:
      window.parent.document.getElementById(this.editor) is null

I searched for it but was unable to solve it. Pls tell me what to do . Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question right you want to use media manager into your custom component for browse images and when select one of image then it's show to your input field. So you can do it by the following method:

In your component open the `models->forms-> open the .xml file` and add the field type as **media** where you want to save the image.

**For example** : *Test.xml*

```
<field id="image"
  name="enter field name"
  type="media"
  label="Select Image"
  description=""
  class="inputbox"
  directory="Enter the image path here" 
/>
```

that's it.Hope this will help.

Comment: Ok got it. Thnx a lot for this solution. Bt It can help me with one image or a fixed number of images but I want that administrator can add any number of images and can even edit the selection of images. what can I do in that case?

Comment: I have displayed a list of all images uploaded by the admin and I provide the option to edit or add a new image.

Comment: @user1934211 do you want to add multiple images for a single item?

Comment: Yes. As I am displaying a slider with all these images.

Comment: @user1934211 You can not do this with the media manger ,if you want to add multiple image on single item.As you say that you want to use it in slider than you can create no. of item in to your component with single image and then display it in to your slider.

Comment: Ok thnx I got that. But let me explain u entire thing I am doing.  I store the path for all the images uploaded at administrator in a database and at the site part, these path and retrieved and a slider is displayed. So at the admin part I need a user interface that helps user to upload a new image, remove it, etc.. and corresponding changes will be made in the database.  I hope you get what I want to do.

Comment: So when a user clicks on 'New', he should be shown a modal to select an image. So I dont think creating an individual items for each image is the only solution.

Comment: @user1934211  I would suggest that it's better to have individual item with it's specific image.So when user click on the new the form will show which have the option select the image then the media manager will open and select image than that image and it's path will save ,and you can easily get all the item to your slider.Hope you got my point.

Comment: Thnx a lot, will do it this way.

Comment: @user1934211 If it helps you can mark it as an answer.check here how to accept http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

The class in a tag must be "modal".

```
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');

<a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 570, y: 400}}" href="index.php?option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&e_name=imageurl&return_url=1"
   title="Image" class="modal">Select</a>
```

Comment: Why? Can you provide a bit more context why this solves the problem, please?